# 'WEEK' function doesn't work when wrapping a CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem using the WEEK function in TSQL

`DATEPHYSICAL` and `DATEEXPECTED` are of type DateTime

```
SELECT 
WEEK((SELECT CASE WHEN DATEPHYSICAL = '1900-01-01' THEN DATEEXPECTED ELSE DATEPHYSICAL END)) as [Week]
FROM 
dbo.table
```

When run the above code it says

> 'WEEK' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Why is this the case? If I remove the `WEEK` function it gives me a column of all the dates as expected, and if I run

```
DATEPART(WEEK,(SELECT CASE WHEN DATEPHYSICAL = '1900-01-01' THEN DATEEXPECTED ELSE DATEPHYSICAL END))
FROM dbo.Table
```

That works as well! Why isn't SQL Server complaining that

> Datepart is not recognized built-in function name

when I use datepart? I'm using Azure SQL Server if that makes any difference.

Comment: `That works as well` ... no it _doesn't_ work, because `WEEK` is not a SQL Server function, it is a MySQL function, [see the demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fed899616d8b221a32b7fef1b6083548).  Use `DATEPART` and everything should be fine.

Comment: I recommend reading the official documentation before asking here.

Comment: FYI its a `case` *expression*, not a *statement*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [DATEPART](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dff194/2) function. The correct syntax is :

```
SELECT DATEPART (WEEK, YourDate)
```

Or,

```
SELECT DATEPART (WW, YourDate)
```

Or,

```
SELECT DATEPART (WK, YourDate)
```

The DATEPART() takes two arguments:

- date_part is the part of a date to be extracted. ( See the valid date
  parts in the table below).
- input_date is the date from which the date part is extracted.

So your query should be like below :
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dff194/2)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Test(DATEPHYSICAL DATE,DATEEXPECTED DATE)
INSERT INTO Test(DATEPHYSICAL,DATEEXPECTED) VALUES ('1900-01-01','2020-01-01'),('2021-01-01','2020-01-01')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK,CASE WHEN DATEPHYSICAL = '1900-01-01' THEN DATEEXPECTED ELSE DATEPHYSICAL END) AS TheWeek FROM Test
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dff194/2/0)**:

```
| TheWeek |
|---------|
|       1 |
|       1 |
```

Answer (score 2):

The error itself, is self descriptor. `WEEK` is a keyword, but is not a function in T-SQL. To get the week of a specific date, you need to use `DATEPART` function.

Here are some samples of using `DATEPART` function to get the week number:

**Using WEEK keyword:**

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE())
```

**Using WEEK keywords's abbreviations:**

```
SELECT DATEPART(ww, GETDATE())
SELECT DATEPART(wk, GETDATE())
```

Finally, you might need to rewrite your query as:

```
SELECT 
       DATEPART(
                WEEK,
                (SELECT CASE WHEN DATEPHYSICAL = '1900-01-01' THEN DATEEXPECTED ELSE DATEPHYSICAL END)
               ) as [Week]
FROM 
dbo.table
```

Read more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#week-and-weekday-datepart-arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATEPART()` which take 2 arguments

Here is an example with `CASE`

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME= GETDATE()
DECLARE @input DATETIME= '2021-01-01'

SELECT DATEPART(WEEK,
                 (SELECT CASE 
                        WHEN CAST(@dt AS DATE) = @input 
                            THEN cast(@dt as DATE)
                        ELSE CAST(@input AS DATE) 
                    END
                  )
                ) as [Week]
```